# Async Task not returning to main thread

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I think this has something to do with my really bad async programming.

Here it goes. I am fetching mailchimp subscribers using an async method but the result just hangs and never returns to main thread.

The async method

```
public async Task<List<Subscriber>> GetMailChimpSubscribers()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<List<Subscriber>> result = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Subscriber>>();
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
        var listId = "";
        var members = await _manager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId);
        foreach (var item in members)
        {
            var sub = new Subscriber();
            sub.Email = item.EmailAddress;
            subscribers.Add(sub);
        }
        result.SetResult(subscribers);
    });
    return result.Task.Result;
}
```

This hangs after result.SetResult(subscribers) statement completely.

This is called from

```
public static List<Subscriber> GetSubscribers()
{
    MailchimpHelper helper = new MailchimpHelper();
    var subscribers= helper.GetMailChimpSubscribers();

    return subscribers.Result;
}
```

What exactly is wrong here? Is the setup wrong?

PS : there isn't an issue with mailchimp or the api , it works great in console. this is purely something bad with async programming

UPDATE:

In case this is faced by someone. the blog helped to clear a lot

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

the working solution from below answers and blog.

```
public async Task<List<Subscriber>> GetMailChimpSubscribers()
   {
    var subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
    var listId = "";
    var members = 
     await   _manager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId).**ConfigureAwait(false)**;

    foreach (var item in members)
    {
        var sub = new Subscriber();
        sub.Email = item.EmailAddress;
        subscribers.Add(sub);
    }

    return subscribers;


} 

public static List<Subscriber> GetSubscribers()
{
    MailchimpHelper helper = new MailchimpHelper();
    var subscribers= helper.GetMailChimpSubscribers();
    subscribers.Wait();

    return subscribers.Result;
}
```

Comment: Your `GetSubscribers()` method needs to be `async` as well, and you have to `await` the the call to `helper.GetMailChimpSubscribers()` instead of calling `.Result`.

Comment: Also, wrapping an already async call in `await Task.Run(async () =>
` is of no use.

Comment: @PeterBons, That's not strictly true, as Task.Run will schedule the asynchronous anonymous method to run in a background thread.  When not using that, the method will execute on the calling thread, which might be the UI thread.

Comment: For clarity, can you tag (or specify) which environment you're using (ASP.net, WPF, etc.)? (Just so it's explicit about whether there's a synchronization context and whether it's possible to use `async` "all the way down").

Comment: Regarding the edit: I would expect this to work in a console application due to the lack of a synchronization context. It's "poorly advertized", but the way async works in a console application is very different than how it works in environments with a synchronization context.

Comment: I love how OP cites a blog post by @StephenCleary as what helped them figure out their problem, but then ignores his advice & answer haha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first part of the problem is that you are, for some weird reason, wrapping the task inside another task. Change your method to this:

```
public async Task<List<Subscriber>> GetMailChimpSubscribers()
{
    var subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
    var listId = "";
    var members = await _manager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId);
    foreach (var item in members) //this foreach could be a simpler LinQ statement
    {
        var sub = new Subscriber();
        sub.Email = item.EmailAddress;
        subscribers.Add(sub);
    }

    return subscribers;
}
```

You should also be calling this method using await, but if this is not possible then change your method to this:

```
public static List<Subscriber> GetSubscribers()
{
    MailchimpHelper helper = new MailchimpHelper();
    var subscribers = helper.GetMailChimpSubscribers();
    subscribers.Wait();
    return subscribers.Result;
}
```

Comment: having it this way , it still hangs on 
var members = await _manager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId);

Only when i put Task<> around it( which i agree is a bad idea), does it atleast shows me results ;)

Comment: @MandarJogalekar can you include the code for GetAllAsync? There's likely another issue there

Comment: that's an sdk method. mailchimp.net nuget package.

Comment: trick was .ConfigureAwait(false) on GetAllAsync(listId). and it worked

Comment: @MandarJogalekar glad it worked. Do look at resizing the foreach into a linq one-liner ;)

Comment: So you point out that the OP shouldn't be wrapping a task in a task needlessly, and then go and add in more code that wraps a task in another task needlessly...

Comment: @Servy where exactly? If you mean on GetSubscribers, it's not exactly the same. See DanBryant's comment on the question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto What is different about it?  In both cases you're simply starting an asynchronous operation in another thread, when you could just as easily let it be started in the current thread, since it's asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy Fixed, thought it was not the same

Answer (score 8):

There's a lot wrong here:

- The actual problem is [blocking on asynchronous code, which causes a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).
- There's also a confusing and unnecessary use of `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.
- It also appears that the `Task.Run` is unnecessary.

Removing all the bad parts leaves us with:

```
public async Task<List<Subscriber>> GetMailChimpSubscribersAsync()
{
  var subscribers = new List<Subscriber>();
  var listId = "";
  var members = await _manager.Members.GetAllAsync(listId);
  foreach (var item in members)
  {
    var sub = new Subscriber();
    sub.Email = item.EmailAddress;
    subscribers.Add(sub);
  }
  return subscribers;
}

public static async Task<List<Subscriber>> GetSubscribersAsync()
{
  MailchimpHelper helper = new MailchimpHelper();
  return await helper.GetMailChimpSubscribersAsync();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you beat me to recommending the article on why you shouldn't block on Async :) - it's by far the best article I'm aware of on why that's a bad idea, btw, it definitely deserves its canonical status.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I'll comment the same I did on @EJoshuaS answer:  this assumes the entry point to GetSubscribersAsync can be an async method

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The fact that this deadlocks kind of implies that there's a synchronization context, though (even though the OP wasn't explicit about that).

Comment: thank you. as suggested by @camilo , my entry point is indeed non async and can't by async.. it's from razor cshtml. so GetSubscribers() method needs to return List<>

Comment: @MandarJogalekar look at my answer then, I showed you how it can be called from a sync method correctly (without causing a deadlock at least). However, you can use `await` in a Razor View

Comment: @MandarJogalekar calling code from a razor file makes no sense, why arent you calling it from the controller action and passing it to the viewmodel?  Or why arent you making an ajax request from the client?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar: Blocking an ASP.NET thread using `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not an ideal solution. Instead, do as maccettura commented and *do all your asynchronous work in the action method*. By the time it gets to the view, you should have a plain 'ol viewmodel object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.Result` in environments with a synchronization context - it creates a circular wait.

In general, try to use `async` "all the way down" if possible - i.e. if you're going to use `async`/`await` at all, you should *only* use `async`/`await`.

Please see [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary for more details.

Comment: While async all the way down is extremely encouraged (and it's correctly so), if the entry point is not async then you cannot use async all the way. This answers assumes the entry point **can** be async

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's true, but that generally occurs in a console app or another environment that lacks a synchronization context (which I was assuming in my answer). I did include the caveat "if possible" to clarify that, though.

Comment: What about WPF? Entry point: UI, has synchronization context and cannot be async (unless an async void handler which provokes other issues)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's true - you are correct that it's not explicit in the post whether the OP can do async "all the way down" (I did edit to include the disclaimer "if possible" to account for the possibility that the OP can't do that). It's much better to do so if possible, though. (`async void` is a separate issue, though - that could cause a race condition, but not a deadlock).

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I commented asking the OP to tag or specify which environment this is in (for clarity).

Comment: My comment seems not to apply since the OP commented that the entry point is a Razor View (I added the asp.net-mvc tag)